# Кроссбраузерная проверка поля на заполненость

Tags: javascript, html

Посоветуйте пожалуйста кроссбраузерную проверку полей на заполненность.
Тобишь что нибудь типа `required="required"`

Answer (score 1):

повесить обработчик

```
textarea.onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value.match(/^[ ]+$/) || this.value == '') { // В значении только пробелы
         submit.disabled = true;
    }
}
```